# Stop tossing a coin at a certain time to violate The Law of Big Number?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose there are $n$ people and each one is tossing a fair coin. They are all using the same strategy, that is : stop tossing when the accumulated number of heads is greater than that of tails($N(\mathbb{heads}) = N(\mathbb{tails}) + 1$).

Then, when we combine everyone's data, obtaining a sequence of tosses, certainly $N_{tot}(\mathbb{heads})$ is much greater than $N_{tot}(\mathbb{tails})$. Let T be the total number of coin tosses, then as $n \to \infty$，is it true that $\frac{N_{tot}(\mathbb{heads})}{T} \to \frac{1}{2}$?

Actually, it is equivalent to dividing the sequence of tosses into groups. And each group satisfies $N(\mathbb{heads}) = N(\mathbb{tails}) + 1$. So by The Law of Big Number, $\frac{N_{tot}(\mathbb{heads})}{T} \to \frac{1}{2}$.

Can we derive this by calculations?

Comment: What if the stopping event never occurs for some people?

Comment: You might look into random walks. What is the stopping time for a symmetric random walk to move $n$ steps to the right?